# C++ passing vector of unique_ptrs as parameters to corresponding element of another equal-length vector (especially parallelly)

Tags: c++, vector, c++11, parallel-processing, unique-ptr

I have:

- vector of `unique_ptr`s of ObjectA
- vector of newly default constructed vector of ObjectB, and
- a function in Object B that has signature `void f(unique_ptr<ObjectA> o)`.

(word Object omitted from here on)

How do I do `Bvec[i].f(Avec[i])` for all `0 < i < length` in parallel?

I have tried using `transform(Bvec.begin(), Bvec.end(), A.begin(), B.begin(), mem_fun_ref(&B::f))`, but it gives a bunch of errors and I'm not sure if it would even pass the right A as parameter, let alone allow me to move them.  `(&B::f(A.begin())` would not work as the last parameter either.

I have also thought of using for_each and then a lambda function, but not sure how to get the corresponding element.  I thought of incrementing a counter, but then I don't think that parallelizes well (I could be wrong).

I can, of course, use a for loop from 0 to end, but I am pretty sure there is a simple thing I'm missing, and it is not parallel with a simple for loop.

Thanks.

Comment: You realize that, by passing a unique pointer, you are *transferring ownership* of those pointers out of the list and into that function, correct? Also, it's not in parallel with `std::transform` either.

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes, I do with the transferring, but no I did not know that transform was not done in parallel..  thanks.  (MTG player?  off topic, nm)

Comment: Do you mean concurrently when you say parallely? `transform` will work ,as every other stdlib algorithm, sequentially. Also, `transform` wont ever work, as it requires a functor that returns something.

Comment: @pmr yes, I guess concurrently.  I can see 2 rows of boxes in my head with an arrow pointing from one row to another which should easily be done at the same time right?

Comment: No, and it will not necessarily be faster than doing it in order. This entirely depends on the amount of work done in `f`.

Comment: How is it supposed to be done in parallel? Do you have some concurrency framework in mind? C++/AMP or so?

Comment: @KerrekSB I was just thinking some library function (or the like) that would just automatically call f in parallel on each element.  similar to the parallel form of for_each.

Comment: @pmr I'm guessing it would be ideally linearly faster, as I do have other functions using object B in the same loop, which then recursively calls this loop function after the transform (I'm building trees if that helps).

Comment: @chemelnucfin There is no standard parallel form of `for_each`. You must be using some framework or library.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a non-parallel implementation using a handmade algorithm. I'm sure someone more versed in the `functional` could come up with a more elegant solution. The problem with `transform` is, that we cannot use it with functions that return `void` and I can't remember another stdlib function that takes two ranges and apply them to each other. If you really want to parallelize this, it needs to be done in the `apply_to` function. Launching an `async` task (e.g. `std::async(*begin++, *begin2++)` could work, although I have no experience with this and cannot get it to work on gcc 4.6.2.

```
#include <iterator>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>


// this is very naive it should check call different versions
// depending on the value_type of iterator2, especially considering
// that a tuple would make sense
template<typename InputIterator1, typename InputIterator2>
void apply_to(InputIterator1 begin, InputIterator1 end, InputIterator2 begin2) {
  while(begin != end) {
    (*begin++)(*begin2++);
  }
}

struct Foo {

};

struct Bar {
  void f(std::unique_ptr<Foo>) { }
};


int main()
{
  std::vector< std::unique_ptr<Foo> > foos(10);
  std::vector< Bar > bars(10);
  std::vector< std::function<void(std::unique_ptr<Foo>) > > funs;

  std::transform(bars.begin(), bars.end(), std::back_inserter(funs),
                 // non-const due to f non-const, change accordingly
                 [](Bar& b) { return std::bind(&Bar::f, &b, std::placeholders::_1); });

  // now we just need to apply each element in foos with funs
  apply_to(funs.begin(), funs.end(), std::make_move_iterator(foos.begin()));


  return 0;
}
```